# Help interpret notation $\sum_{j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_m=n}a^{j_1}_1a^{j_2}_2\cdots a_m^{j_m}$

Tags: summation, notation

I read somewhere that this sum can be written as:
$$\sum_{r+s=n}a_rb_s=\sum_{r=0}^na_rb_{n-r}\tag1$$
This means to create all possible orders of $(r,s)$ and add these together.

> Now, my question is how do you write this summation in terms of the RHS above:
>
> ### $$\sum_{j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_m=n}a^{j_1}_1a^{j_2}_2\cdots a_m^{j_m}=?\tag2$$

Comment: It just means that you sum the value of $a_1^{j_1}\dots$ for all ordered lists $j_1,\dots,j_m$ such that $j_1+\dots+j_m=n$.

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw yes, but I want the notation to be (or $(2)$ be written) like the RHS of $(1)$

Comment: That's going to take multiple summation signs. Are you OK with that?

Comment: @JohnGlenn Why do you want that? Curiosity? To help program it? For an assignment? Would you allow multiple summation symbols with an ellipsis between them or do you just want a single one (or any fixed number?)? All of this context would help.

Comment: @Arthur It only requires multiple summation signs if you restrict yourself to using the exponents as the indices of summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m=3$,

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^{n-r}a_rb_s c_{n-r-s}.$$

For $m=4$,

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^{n-r}\sum_{t=0}^{n-r-s}a_rb_s c_td_{n-r-s-t}.$$

And so on.

Comment: I would say it's a hypertetrahedron which is the hyperface _opposite_ the origin, one dimension higher than the one you think of. It's of little consequence, though.

Comment: @Arthur: that's right, my bad.